# zend session container works on localhost but not in webserver

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

Below is my code:

```
$mysession = new Container('mycart');
$mysession->sessioncart[$productInfo['id']] = $productInfo;
```

`$productInfo['id']` is a product id `$productInfo` is a full product info

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what isn't working about it? Are you getting an error?

Comment: not in webserver means?what have you tested?

Comment: @ferozakbar webserver means where my application hosted.

Comment: @STLMikey  print_r($mysession->sessioncart[$productInfo['id']]);  print nothing.

Comment: no iam asking you how can you say it is not working what have you tetsd>

Comment: Error in log ? more detail on php environment of the remote host ?

Answer (score 1):

After a week I found the reason.

Changing the value of a property of an array in Zend\Session\Container doesn't actually set the changes in the _SESSION object in PHP 5.3.3

Zend\Session\Container not working properly in PHP 5.3.3

You can find details here : https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5137
or https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/4945

Comment: In my localhost php version is php 5.4 and in shared web server where i hosted my application is php 5.3.3 version.